# Unable to find assembly file 'example.dll' while starting windows service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, windows-services, net.tcp

I have developed a WCF service which uses the **net.tcp** binding and **read** and **write** files to the file system. When I start the windows service (in a console) I get following error even if the **sample.dll** is in the folder:

**Unable to find assembly file sample.dll**

This specific WCF service is hosted in a windows service which runs on windows 7 64bit and I have following questions:

Which account should I use for my application:

**User / NetworkService / LocalSystem / LocalService**

And why can’t the OS load the dll even if it is there?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: My guess your problem is this: by default windows service current directory is in windows/system32. So try to move your dll to that directory and try to start service again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is this exact and all exeption message? Can you post more details?

Comment: When I host my WCF service in a console it works perfectly fine the clients are able to connect to the server and are able to get the data pushed by the server through callbacks but the problem is when I host it in a windows service. The service is composed of multiple dlls and the exe + the settings file. I think the problem comes from the credentials of the "account" of the service... the service can't see the dll because he is not allowed to read from the place (currently on my desktop). I don't get any exception.

Comment: For the moment I am using the "User" account for the windows service but I am not sure if it is the correct one?

Comment: You should get exception. Have you looked at event viewer? Have you tried to catch exception and log it? If you catch it you will know the problem. Now you just trying to guess. Also move pdb file with exe then you can get more detailed exception.

Answer (score 3):

For the dll you should add the following line of code right at the beginning of the OnStart method.

```
 System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

That should allow your service to load dlls from the actual directory.

Comment: Nice call - saved me from some misery!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount%28v=vs.80%29) on the ServiceAccount, the User member prompts for a username and password. I'd guess that if you're using the User account and it doesn't have read permissions for windows/system32, that would result in your assembly failing to be found.

Perhaps change the ServiceAccount up a step to a LocalService?